# Create a daily local notification that will start tomorrow

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have an app that reminds user about a todo item every day but I do not not need to remind them if they already did it.

My approach to solve the problem is by creating a local notification that is fired up in a daily basis at a random time. When a todo item is already done for the day, I re-scheduled the local notification day to tomorrow by cancelling it and creating a new one dated for tomorrow. But this solution doesn't work. It seems like when you specify that a local notification is fired daily (repearInterval=NSDayCalendarUnit), it doesn't honour the fireDate day property.

Here is my code:

```
/*** notification is created like this ***/
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.fireDate = [self randomHourMinFromDate:[NSDate date]];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.alertBody = @"A todo item is due!";
localNotif.alertAction = @"View Item";
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;


/*** some other part of the code ***/
NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification *notification = [scheduledNotifications firstObject];

// adds 1 day to notification fireDate
NSDate *newFireDate = [notification.fireData dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*1];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
notification.fireDate = newFireDate;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or perhaps recommend a better solution? TIA!

Comment: You should use NSDateComponents instead of adding this kind of timeInterval to your NSDate.

Comment: I don't think that will change anything. I log the value of newFireDate and it was indeed dated tomorrow. Can you explain what's the difference if I use NSDateComponents instead? (And thank you for the quick answer!)

Comment: It's should be something that should fix your issue. But that something recommended. For example, in France, they are summer/winter time, with one hour difference (so a day of the year has "23 hours" and another one has "25 hours"). So if your date is in this change of hour, you'll get your notification one hour before or one hour later from the hour you set.

Comment: I get it, it is just a recommendation but not a solution to the issue. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I have a idea.  When a todo item is already done for the day, cancel the notification and create a new one. Set firedate to the current date with same time, and set dateByAddingTimeInterval: 60*60*24.

```
localNotification.fireDate = [CurrentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
```

May this could work.